# SQL subtract values by line to find exception

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a pallet query that pulls all pallets, weekly movement, cases on the pallet, and its expiration date (pull date).  Based on weekly movement, I want to see any pallets (with case quantity) that would be remaining once its expiration date hits.

Let's say product A has 2 pallets with 20 cases each, moves 4 cases a day, its expiration date is 1/9/15 and today's date is 1/1/15.  By 1/6/15, the first pallet will be depleted (20 cases on pallet/4 cases per day = 5 days).  By 1/7 pallet two will have 16 cases, by 1/8 pallet two will have 12 cases, and after 1/9 pallet two will have 8 cases.  So for this product, the query would return one line with the pallet number and 8 cases.  So I would want the query to pull only items with cases remaining per the above exercise.  Here is an actual sample of data for a better understanding: (this data was pulled 1/27/15)

```
PLT_NUM   SLOT   ITEM  DESC  PO_NUM    RCV_DT    PULL_DT  MVMNT PLT_QTY
3266414  EJ309D  313  BACON  408326  1/20/2015  3/13/2015   40    48
3320169  EJ309F  313  BACON  409108  1/26/2015  3/16/2015   40    48
3120688  EK318D  314  PIZZA  406066  1/21/2015  4/27/2015    6     7
3287632  EK218L  314  PIZZA  408616  1/22/2015  4/27/2015    6    10
9947873  FQ3030  449  BEANS  271255  1/26/2015  4/17/2015    3     9
9992289  FQ313G  449  BEANS  402066  12/9/2014  4/30/2015    3    12
9992270  FQ307K  449  BEANS  402066  12/9/2014  4/30/2015    3    24
1331883  ZC038H  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/23/2015    0    25
1331892  VE047C  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/24/2015    0    25
1331909  TG172K  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/23/2015    0    25
1331918  ZA040F  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/23/2015    0    25
1331927  ZB040D  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/24/2015    0    25
1331945  ZB040C  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/23/2015    0    25
1331990  ZB040F  906  PASTA  402897  4/22/2008  3/23/2015    0    25
```

Items 313 and 314 would be fine, because they would sell out before the expiration. (Item 313 has 96 cases, at 40 per week, means it will sell in 2.4 weeks.  1/27/15 + 2.4 weeks < 3/13/15).  But item 449 would have a problem.  It has 45 cases, at 3 per week, means it would sell in 15 weeks.  And 1/27/15 + 15 weeks > 4/17/15.  Please let me know if I can clear up any confusion points.